# Converting a pivot table in python to a visualized graph

Tags: python, pandas, graph, pivot

I am trying to convert my pivot table to a plot. This is how I created the pivot:

```
df_posts ['Year_created'] = df_posts['CreationDate'].dt.year
df_posts ['Month_created'] = df_posts['CreationDate'].dt.month
pst_pivot = df_posts.pivot_table(index='Year_created', columns='Month_created', values='Title', aggfunc='count')

pst_pivot.head()
```

[image]

Trying to get this one, or similar:

[image]

THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- define a multi-index
- `unstack()` *year* as columns
- then just `plot()`

```
d = pd.date_range("1-Oct-2011", "1-sep-2013", freq="M")
df = pd.DataFrame({"CreationDate":d, "value":np.random.randint(70,90, len(d))})

df.set_index(pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.CreationDate.dt.year, 
                                        df.CreationDate.dt.month], 
                                       names=["Year_created","Month_created"])).loc[:,"value"].unstack(0).plot()
```

[image]